# Java: Write a generic method that throws any RuntimeException

Tags: java, generics, log4j

I am writing a method that basically does one simple thing, log the error message and throw a runtime exception using the same error message. I want it to be able to throw any child exception of RuntimeException. The method I have got is:

```
public static <T extends RuntimeException> void logErrorAndThrowException(Logger logger, String errorMessage, Class<T> exceptionClazz) throws T {
        logger.error(errorMessage);
        RuntimeException runtimeException = new RuntimeException(errorMessage);
        throw exceptionClazz.cast(runtimeException);   // Not work!!
    }
```

I have have this exception defined:

```
public final class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyException() {
    }

    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public MyException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

I then invoke the method using:

```
   logErrorAndThrowException(logger, "This is an error message", MyException.class);
```

The commented line above will fail with an cast exception. I then tried another implementation of:

```
public static <T extends RuntimeException> void logWarningAndThrowException(Logger logger, String errorMessage, Class<T> exceptionClazz) throws T {
    logger.error(errorMessage);
    try {
        throw exceptionClazz.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // handle
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // handle
    }
}
```

With this implementation, I can only invoke the no-arg constructor of my exception hence cannot set the error message.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: If you declare your method to throw `E` then you can make it throw `E1`, `E2` etc which are subclasses of `E`. Unfortunately, exceptions and generics don't mix too well...

Comment: The more standard solution (and thus, easier to understand for others etc.) is to wrap the Exception as a cause: `throw new RuntimeException(myException)`. This avoids the above problems and keeps the stack trace of the original exception (not just the message), which often helps with debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to grab the appropriate constructor for your exception class before you instantiate it. When you do:

```
throw exceptionClazz.cast(runtimeException);   // Not work!!
```

this cannot work since your class is a subclass of `RuntimeException`.

You can do:

```
final Constructor<T> c = exceptionClazz.getConstructor(String.class);
throw c.newInstance(theMessage);
```

But, really, don't: you'll have to deal with all possible exceptions of those two reflection methods...

Another solution, which does not involve reflection, would be to have an interface such as:

```
public interface ExceptionCreator<T extends RuntimeException>
{
    T doException(String whatsWrong);
}
```

then you have an `IdentityHashMap`:

```
// IdentityHashMap because all Class objects are singletons
private static final Map<Class<? extends RuntimeException>, ExceptionCreator<?>> MAP
    = new IdentityHashMap<>;


// fill the map in a static initialization block
```

Your method would then be:

```
public static <T extends RuntimeException> void logErrorAndThrowException(Logger logger,     
    String errorMessage, Class<T> exceptionClazz) throws T
{
    logger.error(errorMessage);
    // Note: no checks for null here. If null, just throw a "plain" RuntimeException
    throw MAP.get(exceptionClazz).doException(errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: That's the solution I thought of.

Comment: this seems so complex, are you sure you can't just create the exception where you want to log the error?

Comment: @kutschkem not my choice, the OP's ;) I just gave a possible solution to the expressed need ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Exception without throwing it. Since you need to know the class anyway for your method, use the RuntimeException directly as a parameter. There is no point in trying to use reflection here imho.

```
public static <T extends RuntimeException> void logErrorAndThrowException(Logger logger, T exception) throws T {
    logger.error(exception.getMessage());
    throw exception;   // works !!! ;-)
}
```